# Arabic fonts in Linux Mint 19.2 Tina are not displayed properly

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, fonts, cinnamon, language

I've been using mint for about a year now, and found no problems 
so far, but recently i discovered that the Asian fonts are broken:

It started of with a few languages such as Urdu then Arabic:

[image: ِArabic]

[image]

[image]

[image: image description here]

Above font should look like this:

[image]

Could any one help?

Comment: So what is exactly the problem? Which apps are shown in the screenshots? The second one is probably gnome-terminal, but I have no idea about the first. What is the text you enter there? Do they both look broken? Or is the first one correct, the second broken? ... "i discovered that the Asian fonts on the machine" - the Asian fonts what? This sentence doesn't make sense, presumably due to a typo. Instead of just showing two screenshots, could you please also _explain_ what your problem is? Keep in mind that most users here probably can't read Urdu and Arabic.

Comment: Note that gnome-terminal supports right-to-left text beginning with version 3.34, whereas Mint 19.2 seems to have an older one (rendering the characters from left to right, that is, in reverse order). It's not gnome-terminal itself that matters but the underlying VTE library, you need version 0.58 of that to have RTL layout.

Comment: Please don't use tags that have no connection whatsoever with the matter at hand.

Comment: The first snapshot is of the menu, and the only problem is that the font is just broken, i'll add an example of the web, but thanks for answering @egmont.

Comment: The words mean nothing it's just an example, and they both look broken.

Comment: The only problem is the way it looks

Comment: The first problem seems to be that the given input field uses a monospace font, and that's just the way Arabic/Urdu on monospace looks. You should somehow configure that field to use a proportional font. Terminals can only support monospace, even if you upgrade to get RTL support it'll still be monospace with its rendering limitations.

Comment: How do i do that, please ad an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the answer (*Just like egmont said*), i had to change The fonts as following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem, I did what you suggested and it worked for some programs, but still Firefox and some special applications can't handle Arabic/Persian fonts correctly.

I completely realized why this happened and solved it.

**reason this happens**:

I installed cutefish(it's a desktop environment), it created a file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/99-cutefish.conf` and **this file can change the behavior of your fonts** as described here:https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Font_configuration/Examples

I just **removed it** and all the fonts back to the normal (Arabic/Persian and other languages)

You also can change the file as the link above described, but I prefer my desktop environment handle it.